# How can I get specific object key in map iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, iteration

I have one json file and I iterate it with map but I have a deep object key with name 'content' and  I want to get specific key from it when I return my json array with map

JSON:

```
{
  "item": [

    {
       "title": "...",
       "link": "...",
       "content": {
        "_url": "How can I get this :D",
        ...
       }
    }

   ]
}
```

My javascript code:

```
getAllNews = async () => {
    const result = await this.getResource('item/')

    return result.map(this._transformPosts) 
    // Here I iterate my json

}

_transformPosts = (item) => {

    return {
       title: item.title, 
       link: item.link,
       image: item.content._url, 
       // and here I try get _url
       id: item.guide,

    }

}
```

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: You have a typo: `item.conten._url`

Comment: I know it's dont change anything

Comment: I want return` content._url` to `image` ?

Comment: `image: (item.content && item.content._url) ? item.content._url : ''` should be enough.

Comment: @briosheje Wow it's work, thank you man

Comment: @Muhammed nice, I've answered below, feel free to accept the answer if that's what you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly handle all cases, remember to always check whether the property effectively exists:

```
return {
       title: item.title, 
       link: item.link,
       image: (item.content && item.content._url) ? item.content._url : '', // <-- fix here.
       id: item.guide,

    }
```

Possible issues probably were:

- Typo on your line: `item.conten._url,` (should be `content`)
- `item` with missing `content`. In that case, `item.content._url` would raise an exception. Adding a ternary operator like I did above will ensure the property exists, otherwise it will set the default value to `''`. Feel free to change it if that's not the intended default value.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to get item key and It an array. Lets iterate over it and get the key you want to fetch

```js
let jsonData = {
    "item": [
  
      {
         "title": "title",
         "link": "link",
         "content": {
          "_url": "How can I get this :D"
         }
      }
  
     ]
  }
   function getKeyFromObject(obj,key){

          return obj.item.map(each=>each.content[key])
      }
      
  const url = getKeyFromObject(jsonData,"_url");
  console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return {
   title: item.title, 
   link: item.link,
   image: item['content']['_url'], 
   id: item.guide,
}
```